# realizar conteo SQL

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

tengo el siguiente query

```
SELECT 
tpf.NumeroPago, tpf.Capital, tpf.FechaPago

FROM tle_pp_final tpf 
WHERE tpf.Id='00900215015'
```

el cual me arroja el siguiente resultado

```
NumeroPago  Capital              FechaPago
1               0.00        2023-01-05 00:00:00
2               0.00        2023-02-05 00:00:00
3               0.00        2023-03-05 00:00:00
4               0.00        2023-04-05 00:00:00
5               0.00        2023-05-05 00:00:00
6               245055.18   2023-06-05 00:00:00
7               0.00        2023-07-05 00:00:00
8               0.00        2023-08-05 00:00:00
9               0.00        2023-09-05 00:00:00
10              0.00        2023-10-05 00:00:00
11              0.00        2023-11-05 00:00:00
12              248322.58   2023-12-05 00:00:00
13              0.00        2024-01-05 00:00:00
14              0.00        2024-02-05 00:00:00
15              0.00        2024-03-05 00:00:00
16              0.00        2024-04-05 00:00:00
17              0.00        2024-05-05 00:00:00
18              251633.55   2024-06-05 00:00:00
```

lo que quiero es una forma de poder identificar las cuotas donde salga 0 hasta antes donde pague capital, por ejemplo, en la muestra anterior quiero identificar que hay 5 cuota de capital 0 hasta el numero de pago 6 que es donde ya comienza a pagar capital, y obtener cuantos dias hay hasta pagar la primer cuota además de la fecha en la que paga capital

por ejemplo para el caso que comparto espero este resultado:

```
No Cuotas       Dias       Fecha
   5             180    2023-06-05 00:00:00
```

que son 180 días desde el numeroPago 1 hasta el numero pago 6

como puedo hacer para obtener el resultado que quiero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que siempre se cumple la condición de que el número de pago y la fecha de pago son crecientes en cada registro, se puede resolver este problema encontrando primero los *grupos* de pago (también puedes llamarle *islas* de pago), por ejemplo, con esta consulta podemos obtener el registro *final* de cada grupo (que es el registro dónde se paga capital) y, valiéndonos de la función [`lag()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql), el número de pago dónde debiera iniciar dicho grupo, que es el número de pago final del grupo anterior más uno.

```
select   tpf.NumeroPago 
       , tpf.FechaPago
       , coalesce(LAG(tpf.NumeroPago) over (order by  tpf.FechaPago), 0) + 1 NumeroPagoInicial
  from tle_pp_final tpf
 where tpf.Id = '00900215015'
   and tpf.Capital <> 0
```

Luego, podemos poner dicha consulta en un CTE y obtener el resto de datos del *grupo* de pago, por ejemplo, si a dicho CTE le llamamos `GrupoPago`, podríamos obtener el número de pago y la fecha inicial del mismo, contar la cantidad de pagos que componen el grupo y obtener el número de días que ha transcurrido entre ambas fechas.

Para realizar estos cálculos podemos valernos del operador [`apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql#left_table_source--cross--outer--apply-right_table_source), por ejemplo:

```
select   *
       , DATEDIFF(day, DatosGrupo.FechaPagoInicioGrupo, GrupoPago.FechaPago) DiasPagoGrupo
  from GrupoPago
       outer apply (select   min(NumeroPago) NumeroPagoInicioGrupo
                           , min(FechaPago) FechaPagoInicioGrupo
                           , count(1) NumeroCuotas
                      from tle_pp_final
                     where Id = '00900215015'
                       and NumeroPago >= GrupoPago.NumeroPagoInicial
                       and NumeroPago < GrupoPago.NumeroPago
                   ) DatosGrupo
```

Finalmente, si quieres integrar estos datos en la consulta general de pagos, podrías ir colocáncolas en CTE's y hacer un join al final con la misma. Esta consulta devuelve todas las cuotas, y cada cuota de pago de capital tiene los datos de su *grupo* de pago:

```
with
GrupoPago as (
select   tpf.NumeroPago 
       , tpf.FechaPago
       , coalesce(LAG(tpf.NumeroPago) over (order by  tpf.FechaPago), 0) + 1 NumeroPagoInicial
  from tle_pp_final tpf
 where tpf.Id = '00900215015'
   and tpf.Capital <> 0
)
,
DatosGrupoPago as (
select   GrupoPago.NumeroPago NumeroPagoFinGrupo
       , DATEDIFF(day, DatosGrupo.FechaPagoInicioGrupo, GrupoPago.FechaPago) DiasPagoGrupo
       , DatosGrupo.NumeroCuotas
  from GrupoPago
       outer apply (select   min(FechaPago) FechaPagoInicioGrupo
                           , count(1) NumeroCuotas
                      from tle_pp_final
                     where Id = '00900215015'
                       and NumeroPago >= GrupoPago.NumeroPagoInicial
                       and NumeroPago < GrupoPago.NumeroPago
                   ) DatosGrupo
)
select   tpf.NumeroPago
       , tpf.Capital
       , tpf.FechaPago
       , dip.NumeroCuotas
       , dip.DiasPagoGrupo Dias
  from tle_pp_final tpf
        left join DatosGrupoPago dip on dip.NumeroPagoFinGrupo = tpf.NumeroPago
 where tpf.Id = '00900215015'
```

Con los datos del ejemplo, devolvería:

```
NumeroPago  Capital        FechaPago  NumeroCuotas Dias
----------- -------------- ---------- ------------ ----
1           0.00           2023-01-05 NULL         NULL
2           0.00           2023-02-05 NULL         NULL
3           0.00           2023-03-05 NULL         NULL
4           0.00           2023-04-05 NULL         NULL
5           0.00           2023-05-05 NULL         NULL
6           245055.18      2023-06-05 5            151
7           0.00           2023-07-05 NULL         NULL
8           0.00           2023-08-05 NULL         NULL
9           0.00           2023-09-05 NULL         NULL
10          0.00           2023-10-05 NULL         NULL
11          0.00           2023-11-05 NULL         NULL
12          248322.58      2023-12-05 5            153
13          0.00           2024-01-05 NULL         NULL
14          0.00           2024-02-05 NULL         NULL
15          0.00           2024-03-05 NULL         NULL
16          0.00           2024-04-05 NULL         NULL
17          0.00           2024-05-05 NULL         NULL
18          251633.55      2024-06-05 5            152

(18 rows affected)
```

Finalmente acotar que, como puedes ver, entre el 5 de enero y el 5 de junio de 2023 hay 151 días, y no 180, como afirmas en la pregunta.

Comment: he realizado esa consulta, sin embargo me generan otros resultados

por ejemplo en la cuota 6 me genera

6 245055.18 2023-06-05 00:00:00 261795 5831

Comment: Al final, tienes razón, había olvidado incluir una condición el en `where` del `outer apply`, que creo hubieras podido pillar y corregir por ti mismo. Ya está actualizada la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Según entiendo tu quieres identificar la primera cuota de valor cero y la primera cuota mayor a cero. Y luego obtener la diferencia en días entre ambas.

*A modo de nota, me parece que tu ejemplo tiene un error, entre `2023-01-05` y `2023-06-05` hay 151 días, no 180 como has señalado tu*

Para obtener el resultado simplemente haces:

```
SELECT 
  ultimo.NumeroPago - 1 as 'No Cuotas',
  DATEDIFF(day,primero.FechaPago,ultimo.FechaPago) as "Dias",
  ultimo.FechaPago as "Fecha"
from
 (select top 1 * FROM tle_pp_final where Capital=0 order by FechaPago) as primero,
 (select top 1 * FROM tle_pp_final where Capital>0  order by FechaPago ) as ultimo
```

Resultado

| No Cuotas | Dias | Fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 151 | 2023-06-05T00:00:00Z |

Evidentemente el `TOP 1` es para MSSQL, dependiendo del motor tu tendrás que ocupar `LIMIT 1` o cualquier función para obtener la primera fila